# How do I construct a zend controller for a command line process

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a command line process that needs to use code in one of my controllers. When I try to construct the controller, I get an error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Zend_Controller_Action::__construct() must be an instance of Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract, none given,
```

I assume the controller wants the request so it can do routing etc. How do I call the action for the controller from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the code I needed for my controller into the model. I suppose it was in the wrong place anyhow as it didn't talk to a view.